# Updating value of an object within an array life cycle

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am trying to console.log the value of an array through a series of process. This for debugging but to also help me see how javascript methods alter reference types like arrays and objects.

In this situation I am logging the value of an object within an array that is also within an object of an array:

## Sample model:

```
{key: '1234', class: 'Math 10', fname: 'john', lname: 'doe',
    homework: [
      {key: '123', check: 'yes'},
      {key: '12356', check: 'no'},
      {key: '12356789', check: 'na'},
    ]
    },
```

What I am trying to alter is the value of the 'check' within each homework object.

## The problem/confusion

When a console log the homework object to monitor the value of 'check' while I writing my code, the moment I change the value of 'check', all previous console logs show this new value.

How is this possible when I have set the value at the exact point in time? I thought it had something to do with reference types but I using the slice method to ensure I am copying the array.

```
    const value = event.target.getAttribute("data-value");
    console.log("data-value is = ", value);

    const studentKey = event.target.getAttribute("data-studentkey");
    console.log("student key is = ", studentKey);

    const selectedHomeworkKey = this.state.selectedHomework;
    console.log("Seleted Homework Key is ", selectedHomeworkKey);

    const students = this.state.students.slice();
    console.log("state says students are", students);

    const selectedStudents = students.filter((student)=>{
      return( student.key === studentKey);
    })
    console.log("After filter, students is ", selectedStudents);

    const nonSelectedStudents = students.filter((student)=>{
      return( student.key !== studentKey);
    })
    console.log("Non selected students are ", nonSelectedStudents);

    const homeworkArray = selectedStudents[0].homework.slice();
    console.log("homework of the selected student is ", homeworkArray);

    const selectedHomework = homeworkArray.filter((homework) => {
      return (homework.key === selectedHomeworkKey);
    })
    console.log("selected homework for selected student is ", selectedHomework);

    let updatedHomework = selectedHomework.slice();
    console.log("updated homework before update is", updatedHomework)

    updatedHomework[0].check = value;
    console.log("updated homework after update is", updatedHomework)
```

[image]

## The Question

Why is the value of check 'yes' showing up in all previous console.logs even though it should only be showing this value in the last console.log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're using React you should avoid mutating the state. And that's exactly what you're doing in your code. If `this.state.students` is an array of objects `.slice()` will not take any effect (when you'll try to change some object's property in an array you sliced from another array the property will be changed in the source array too)

You may want some immutability helper to change your state easier. I use https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper

You can try to deep clone the whole object if you need. Take a look at https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep

As a workaround you can also use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));` to quickly clone objects.

Comment: It was indeed a deep cloning issue, I didn't realize this applied to arrays with objects or arrays in it.

Using the ```JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array);``` worked perfectly.